# C# Generic Interface with different return types

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have webservice that can return data in multiple formats. For example json and xml. I'm building a simple C# api against this webservice and I would like the methods to be able to return either fully serialized objects from json, raw json or raw xml. For example:

```
List<Order> GetOrders(int customerId)
string GetOrders(int customerId)
XMLDocument GetOrders(customerId)

Customer GetCustomer(int customerId)
string GetCustomer(int customerId)
XMLDocument GetCustomer(int customerId)
```

I have an idea about doing a fluent api where you would call a SetFormat() method which would then return a common Interface for the above methods. But I'm stuck on how that interface would look like, since the implementation that returns serialized objects returns objects of different types.

Another simpler solution would to just have the methods that return serialized objects and then add an out paramater like this:

```
List<Order> GetOrders(int customerId, out string data)
```

but that's not very nice solution I think....

**UPDATE**

I prefered the none-generic solution that Sjoerd suggested, I had over-complicated my problem. This is what I ended up doing:

```
public class ServiceEntity {
    List<Order> GetOrders(int customerId)....
}    
public class ServiceJson {
    string GetOrders(int customerId)....
}
public class ServiceXml {
    XmlDocument GetOrders(int customerId)....
}
```

Then a fluent service class like this:

```
public class Service : IService {
    ....
    public AsJson() { return new ServiceJson(); }
    public AsEntity() { return new ServiceEntity(); }
    public AsXml() { return new ServiceXml(); }
}
```

Used like this:

```
string json = Service.New().AsJson().GetCategories(1);
List<Order> = Service.New().AsEntity().GetCategories(1);
```

Thanks for all the replies!

Comment: Your approach couples 'how to format the output' and 'how to get the info'. It's better to decide on one type that has all the info you need, e.g. `List<Order>`. Then, if you ever want to change the format, your code for 'how to get the info' does not need to change. And if you want to get the info from a different source, your 'how to format the output' code does not need to change. **Decoupled code is much more maintainable**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nice to try to use generics, but generics are not a silver bullet!

In this case, I wonder how much code would you save compared with the non-generic:

```
List<Order> GetOrdersAsList(int customerId)
string GetOrdersAsString(int customerId)
XMLDocument GetOrdersAsXml(customerId)
```

I bet almost none!

And in case you decide on the non-generic approach, most likely it would end up internally as:

```
List<Order> GetOrders(int customerId)
string OrdersToString(List<Order> orders)
XMLDocument OrdersToXml(List<Order> orders)
```

Then the latter two methods could be moved to separate classes, resulting in the fact that your `GetOrders()` is uncoupled from the format.

That seems to me a much better and cleaner approach than trying to use generics in this case!

**UPDATE**: Don't get me wrong, I like generics and in many cases they make code more readable. Several other answers are very interesting as they show techniques to achieve that. So I recommend to study them: they might be useful in other cases. But **in this case**, each proposed solution so far has a practical drawback. That's why I recommend non-generics in this case.

Comment: I think you're right on this one. I was overthinking the problem. I still think my fluent api would have been nice, but it's just too complex.

Comment: @ZMS Don't get me wrong: I would love it when a generic approach would work. I have searched for one many times. But I never got a satisfactionary result in cases like this :(. Of course, the fact that I couldn't find one, does not mean that there is none. So I'm hoping someone posts a great answer, proving me wrong (I won't hold my breath, though).

Answer (score 3):

You could also have a look at using an implicit operator to return the data as expected.

For example the following class:

```
public class OrderThingy 
{
    public static implicit operator List<Order>(OrderThingy orderthingy)
    {
        // Use CustomerId to get the data
        return new List<Order>();
    }

    public static implicit operator string(OrderThingy orderthingy)
    {
        // Use CustomerId to get the data
        return "string representation";
    }

    public static implicit operator XDocument(OrderThingy orderthingy)
    {
        // Use CustomerId to get the data
        return new XDocument();
    }

    private int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public OrderThingy GetOrders(int customerId)
    {
        CustomerId = customerId;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
XDocument doc = new OrderThingy().GetOrders(1);
List<Order> orders = new OrderThingy().GetOrders(2);
string stringorders = new OrderThingy().GetOrders(2);
```

Comment: I don't think this can be used in a generic context, as there is no common type to which the generic can be restricted. That is, there is no `void Foo<T>() where T = ??? { T result = new OrderThingy().GetOrders(1); }`

Comment: Interesting solution, but I think Sjoerd is right about the generic context.

Comment: I have to say I don't completely get what Sjoerd means.. Why would you combine this with generics? You know if you should return XDoc, List<Order> or string so you just fetch the correct results in the implicit methods?

Comment: I might have spoken too soon. However using this approach the user using the API would have to know what types the different methods returns? It's not "alright I'll call this method and get this back", but "alright I'll call this method and let me check the docs, yes it's supposed to be able to return a Dictionary<string, int>..."

Comment: @WouterdeKort One uses generics for a reason. In this case, you provide neither less code, nor can your solution be used in a generic context (allowing saving on code elsewhere). Here you use a `static implicit operator`, which is a somewhat obscure construct compared with the traditional `GetOrdersAsXmlDocument()`. That's ok when there is a gain elsewhere, as I always like to simplify things for the caller of one's code. But I don't see any benefit to the caller in this case. Being able to be used in a generic context would be good enough for me, but sadly it cannot.

Comment: @Wouter de Kort Still, I have upvoted your answer for the clever use of `static implicit operator` to achieve overloading on return value, which I might start to use in other contexts.

Comment: @Sjoerd I've used the static implicit operator to in the context of a builder pattern. I've used the following:   public static implicit operator EntityType(Builder<EntityType> builder)
        {
            return builder.Construct();
        }

Answer (score 2):

Just create a generic return class

```
public class FormattedClass<T>
{
    List<T> ItemList { get; set; }
    string Json { get; set; }
    XmlDocument Document { get; set; }
}

public FormattedClass<T> GetItems<T>(long primaryKey)
```

Comment: So you want to generate a full `XmlDocument` even when the caller is only interested in the `List<T>`?

Comment: I am not sure what the requirements are for his service.  It looked like from his example that he at least needed a List and JSON at the same time.

Comment: I only need one format returned at once. However this is a solution that'll work. It's simple to check which format the user wants returned and then only set the corresponding property on the FormatedClass. The ugly part is that you'll always get an object where two of the properties are null, instead of getting only the requested format.

Answer (score 1):

What about a method

```
private class WebService
{
    public T GetOrders<T>(int customerId)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(List<Order>))
        {
            return new List<Order>();
        }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return "42";
        }
    }
}
```

and depending on the type you provide on call, like:

```
var webService = new WebService();

var a = webService.GetOrders<List<Order>>();
var b = webService.GetOrders<string>();
```

you return the expected value.

Comment: That would require that the user using the API would need to know the return values.

Comment: @ZNS and in that case, why not just use `var a = webService.GetOrdersAsString();` ?

Comment: @ZNS The compiler needs to know what `T` is when calling the generic method. So either the user has to provide it, or the compiler must be able to deduce it. One can postpone that decision by embedding the call in a generic context, but at some point one hits a non-generic context (e.g. Main() ) and one has to make that decision anyway. As the original question is yours, you seem to want to achieve something that is unachievable.

Comment: @ZNS The user using the API *have* to know how to handle with the return values !!!

Answer (score 1):

what about generics ?

```
T GetOrders<T>(int customerID)
```

Comment: And how do you propose to implement the `GetOrders<T>`?

Comment: List<Order> a = service.GetOrders<List<Order>>(10);
string b = service.GetOrders<string>(10);

Comment: same solution as Fischermaen's

Comment: Yes, it wasnt there when i posted

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps encapsulate the different return types into a single common type:

```
CustomerResult GetCustomer(int customerId)
```

where

CustomerResults has:

```
Get/SetFormat()
Get/SetCustomer()
Get/SetXmlDoc()
Get/SetString()
```

etc.